# In the finite field $F$ of characteristic $p$, is $a^{p^n} = a$?

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields

If F is a finite field of characteristic $p$, $a$ is some element in $F$ and the number of elements in $F$ is $p^n$, is it true that $a^{p^n} = a$ for all $a$ in $F$? If it is, how could one prove or motivate that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$F-0$ is a group of order $p^n-1$, so $x^{p^n-1}=1$ if $x\neq 0$. This implies that $x^{p^n}=xx^{p^n-1}=x$ if $x\neq 0$. the result. Obviously, $x^{p^n}=x$ if $x=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: look at the multiplicative group.

Answer (score 1):

Every finite subgroup of the multiplicative group of a field is cyclic.  As the multiplicative group of a field of order $p^n$ is finite of order $p^n-1$ the result follows.

Comment: Though it is true that a finite subgroup of the multiplicative group of a field is cyclic, this is not necessary, since $g^{m}=1$ in every finite group of order $m$.

Comment: @Shoutre is absolutely correct.  Note to self: no stack exchange while tired.